# Mask/alter displayed values from a datagrid column in a datagridview

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2012, datagridview, sql-server-2012, dataset

Ok guys, having an issue. I'm building a vb.NET Windows Application to enter and retrieve data from a SQL Server 2012 database. Because the data has HIPPA elements, I am required (non-negotiable) to have the ability to Hide/Show the Private Health Information (PHI) on demand (based on user authorization). I accomplished this by creating a persistent shell form with a panel that the other forms can load into. In the shell, I created a button that sets a variable to Show/Hide and a routine that can be called by any of the other forms to Show/Hide their individual PHI fields by setting the passwordchar for each PHI field on that particular form. It works perfectly for everything, except for DataGridViews. Is there any way to do something similar for a column in a data grid view (change the display value to something similar to a passwordchar without changing the actual data held in the dataset by the application)?

I realize that I could create a view in the SQL database and overwrite the dataset table every time the Show/Hide button is clicked, but there seems like there should be a more elegant way to do this. Looking forward to your responses.

Here is the code for the Hide/Show PHI checkbox (button type) in the shell form:

```
Private Sub chkTogglePHI_CheckedChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles chkTogglePHI.CheckedChanged 

    WorkingAreaForm.ShowPHI(chkTogglePHI.Checked)
    HeaderForm.ShowPHI(chkTogglePHI.Checked)

    If chkTogglePHI.Checked = False Then 
        chkTogglePHI.Text = "Show PHI"
    Else 
        chkTogglePHI.Text = "Hide PHI"
    End If

End Sub
```

Here's an example of the code called by a subform:

```
Public Sub ShowPHI(val As Boolean) Implements IFormMethods.ShowPHI
    If val = False Then
        txtFirstName.PasswordChar = ""
        txtMI.PasswordChar = ""
        txtLastName.PasswordChar = ""
    Else
        txtFirstName.PasswordChar = "*"
        txtMI.PasswordChar = "*"
        txtLastName.PasswordChar = "*"
    End If 
End Sub
```

This code works great for any textboxes that hold PHI, but I don't know an equivalent to mask/unmask PHI columns shown in a datagridview.

The iFormMethods is just an interface that allows the shell form to call the sub for whatever form may be loaded onto the panel in the shell form. The "val" argument in the ShowPHI sub grabs the current value of the shell.chkTagglePHI.Checked object.

Comment: Do you have any code that you can share?

Comment: Bottom line, through an interface, the shell can tell any subform to activate it's show/hide PHI sub based on the shell button checked state. If it is to hide PHI, it sets the passwordchar for each PHI object to *. If it is to show PHI, it sets the passwordchar for each PHI object to an empty string (showing the PHI values). The problem is, I don't know how to do something similar to the FirstName column of a datagridview without overwriting the underlying values in the dataset table. In the case of the subjects datagridview, the table loaded into the dataset is 225k rows, and I'd rather not..

Comment: ...pull a view of that table with masked values for the PHI fields, then dispose it and grab the real values in a new table (or hold both versions in system memory). And apologies for the cramped code. New to these forums and not sure how to make the text render line breaks.

Comment: it would be best if you added the information from your comments to your original post with the correct formatting for readability.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's one way:

1. Add another column to the dataset with the mask (e.g. "*****")
2. Give both columns the same HeaderText value, and hide one or the
   other based upon the value of the PHI field, as shown here:

   ```
   Public Sub ShowPHI() Implements IFormMethods.ShowPHI
     MyGrid.Columns("realNameColumn").Visible = Not shell.chkTagglePHI.Checked
     MyGrid.Columns("hiddenNameColumn").Visible = shell.chkTagglePHI.Checked
   End Sub
   ```